# Make FRITZ!Box 7580 and Cisco WAP 121 work as one WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, fritzbox

My old Fritz!Box has not supported WLAN so I bought the Cisco WAP121. The new Router (Fritz!Box 7580) supports WLAN. Because of the fact that the two devices stand at other places in the house, sometimes the connection to the Fritz!Box is better, sometimes the connection to the Cisco WAP.

Is it possible to configure the WAP 121 as a Repeater with his own Wired LAN?

Edit:
Here a little picture:
[image]
So I wan't the WAP121 work as a Repeater but because I think that a wired connection is faster than a wireless connection between the router and the repeater, I would like to use the cable.
If a device "moves" in the area it should always pick the best connection.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: Erm, yes. The proper term is repeater bridge.

Comment: Still not, what I'm looking for. I've added a little picture and some extra information. I hope it's more easy now to understand, what I want.